# JPA native query to QueryDSL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, query-optimization, querydsl

I am using the following query to fetch records from MySQL database:

```
SELECT m.manuf_code
     , m.manuf_display_name
     , m.record_timestamp
     , m.record_status 
  FROM manufacturers m 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT manuf_code
           , MAX(record_timestamp) AS maxdate 
        FROM manufacturers 
           WHERE record_status = 'N' OR record_status = 'U' 
         GROUP 
          BY manuf_code) mn
    ON m.manuf_code = mn.manuf_code 
   AND m.record_timestamp = mn.maxdate
```

There are about 10 million records in DB.

These records are fetched from a Java Application, which is causing Timeout.
The same query works well on Database level and I was able to optimize this using Indexes.

Is it worth trying to convert this query to JPAQuery (QuerDSL) and the give a try to fetch records. Will it be any faster ?
Assuming there are Foreign key references, which JPA fetches internally.
If it is good enough to try, please suggest the equivalent Query DSL for the native query !

EDIT:

This Query fetches the latest records from the table.
This table will have around 2 Million records, so when through JPA repository, I make a call to fetch these many records, it goes in waiting and eventually times out.
One solution is to use the same native query and perform Pagination while fetching records.

I was wondering if there is a way apart from paginating to fetch those many records.

I might be very wrong. I now realize this is not an issue with my query but with the fact that fetching 2 million records from DB is not a good choice.

Comment: The benefit from using QueryDSL is mostly the fluency of the API: the queries written in Java are more readable vs. JPA Criteria queries and moreover, type-safe vs native queries. I doubt that the SQL generated by QueryDSL will be more performant vs the native one; odds are that it's more complex and has poorer performance.

Comment: Are you sure it's this exact native query that's giving you the timeout? What do you mean that it performs well on the DB level? How does the execution plan look like?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Please see my EDIT.

Comment: Hmm.. okay, if the query result set has 2M rows, then that's probably your problem even if the execution plan itself would be optimal. What are you doing with the data? Is this a one-time operation that could be handled with a plain SQL script?

Comment: So this 2M data I have to move from one table to another table (different database).
Please excuse, as this is the requirement.
Also, not using any Stored Procedure for this. Plain JAVA for this data movement.

Comment: So, at once I cannot fetch this many.
This is why Pagination could be helpful.
Please suggest !

Comment: I would use bulk export/import tools of the source/target DB for this task. You could probably make it work with JPA+paging, so that you only read some thousands of rows at a time and then import those into the target db. But you might run into transaction timeout issues (the default timeout values would need to be adjusted).